# Defined \acronymname is not used in toc, but the standard "Acronyms", why?

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, acronyms

I have defined a new name for my Acronyms list, but it the default name ("Acronyms") is used in the table of contents. Do you know how I can solve this?

I have created a minimum working example, but it doesn't have the problem, so here is some of my code. Is there a problem here, or should I look somewhere else?

```
...
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-superragged}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Acronyms and Abbreviations}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} % remove trailing dot
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newacronym{hci}{HCI}{Human-Computer Interaction}
\newacronym{dom}{DOM}{Document Object Model}
\newacronym{svg}{SVG}{Scalable Vector Graphics}
...

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
    \includepdf[pages={-}]{front_page.pdf}
    \setcounter{page}{1}    
    \input{abstract}
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    \printglossary[style=super, type=\acronymtype]
    \input{preface}
\mainmatter
    ...
```

Comment: Did you run Latex twice?  Is the old name still used after the second run?

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else, because your example (not a MWE, anyway) works fine, unless you forgot what @Thruston mentioned in his/her comment.

Comment: Yes, I have run it many times. And the name changes above the list, but not in the toc. The toc just shows "Acronyms".

Comment: I found a solution: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acronymname}` right after `\printglossary[style=super, type=\acronymtype]`. And I removed the `toc` option from the glossaries package. I don't get why this works, and not the other way.

Comment: If you are interested in finding where the source of the problem was, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, that reproduce it. Yours is just a workaround, since this must be done directly with the `toc` option in `glossaries`.

Comment: @swenedo You should turn your comment/update into an answer if it worked for you, in order to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround which solved my problem. I added a `\addcontentsline{toc}` right after I print the acronym list.

```
\printglossary[style=super, type=\acronymtype]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acronymname}
```

and I removed the `toc` option from the glossaries package.

Comment: This won't show the correct page number if the list of acronyms is longer than a page.